# Code Quality for Sales Force

Tags: salesforce, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I wanted to do a code analysis for Sales Force track. I am currently using CAST tool for other tracks such as Java, SAP etc. But Sales Force is not supported my CAST tool. Kindly let me know if there is any alternate Licensed tool that supports Sales Force for code analysis.

thanks,
Sreeram

Answer (score 0):

There are list of tools which you can use for static code analysis on SF projects:

- [CodeScan](https://www.code-scan.com/)
- [ApexMetrics](https://github.com/Up2Go/codeclimate-apexmetrics)
- [PMD](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.0/) provides [Apex language module](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.0/pmd-apex/rules/index.html)